# Please reopen question edited to be more general

Tags: support, closed-questions

A user had recently asked how to connect an Android 4 device to Ubuntu:
[How to connect MTP devices via USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146529/how-to-connect-samsung-galaxy-s3-via-usb)

As Android no longer supports USB Mass Storage, this is a very pertinent question. However, the question as originally asked was specific to the Samsung Galaxy S3 device. I have edited the question to be more general. Please reopen the edited question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for editing and requesting reopening. I see the question has been reopened.